Finding the Determinant of a Specific Tridiagonal Matrix
Given the matrix $A$:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b_1^* & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
b_1 & a & b_2^* & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b_2 & a & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-2}^* & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & b_{n-2} & a & b_{n-1}^* \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & b_{n-1} & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and the element at $(i,j)$ is zero if $j > i+1 $ or $j < i-1$.
The determinant of $A$ is denoted by $D_n$. The initial conditions and recurrence relation are given by:

$D_0 = 1$
$D_1 = a$
$D_2 = a^2 - |b_1|^2$
For $n \geq 3, D_n = a D_{n-1} - |b_{n-1}|^2 D_{n-2}$

How can I find a general expression for $D_n$?
I appreciate any help or insight you can provide.

Not that it matters, but you have the recursion starting at $n=3$, but it does hold for $n=2$.

A close formula comes from proposition 5 of Mallik, R. K. (2001). "The inverse of a tridiagonal matrix". Linear Algebra and its Applications. 325: 109–139. doi:10.1016/S0024-3795(00)00262-7, but you have to adapt it to your case

If you write down the first 10 or so $D_n$ and collect terms, then a pattern starts to appear. I did the first 6, but think you need a few more.
